# react-bootstrap: Nav without NavItem?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Maybe I am just stupid or prejudiced, but I really really don't like [`NavItem`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs). The fact that it is an `<a>` wrapped inside an `<li>` enforces a lot of rules that I don't want to abide by. I just want to create my own Navbar using the Bootstrap stylings, but with my own elements, like `<Button>`, `<ButtonGroup>`, maybe an unclickable image or even a search box.

Which leads me to my question: What is the easiest way to get rid of `NavItem` and get (somewhat) properly styled, ordered elements?

If I simply put a `<li><Button>...</Button></li>` in `<Nav>`, it complains about properties that are not expected by `<li>`. I tried replacing `<Nav>` with my own `<ul>` while copying all it's properties and it still did not work out well. I imagine, just playing around like that will eventually work but easily break in the future because I am not respecting some of `Navbar`'s design considerations.

Is `Navbar` only to be used with `<Nav>` and links? If I want non- elements in my bar, do I have to do the whole thing from scratch? There must be a better solution...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you find it easier to make your component or change the bootstrap components  and